# Porting from Linux to Windows 8: Struct member names

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, wdk

I'm porting some (working) code from Linux to Windows 8. I'm using DDK.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int test1;
    unsigned int test2;
} settings;

const settings vp_settings = {
    .test1 = 1,
    .test2 = 1
};
```

What is different about the Windows DDK compiler and GCC that makes this invalid? The error I'm getting, assuming `typedef struct {` is line 1 and numbering continues normally:

> (7) : error: C2059: syntax error : '.'

How can I write this in such a way that there will be no syntax errors? I would like to keep the same member names so I don't need to alter the rest of the code base. Is the period superfluous and can be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: What's wrong with (vanilla):

```
const settings vp_settings = {
    1, /* test1 */
    1  /* test2 */
};
```

PS:

[How to rewrite C-struct designated initializers to C89 (resp MSVC C compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440611/how-to-rewrite-c-struct-designated-initializers-to-c89-resp-msvc-c-compiler)

This looks like a C99 thing ... and AFAIK MSVS does *not* fully support C99...

Comment: @sarnold - I understand. My point was that Microsoft has never been accused of being very agressive about supporting the latest/greatest open standards, and the best approach is probably, as the link above suggests, "Just drop the field name tags".  IMHO...

Comment: Silly me to expect them to implement a neat feature only 13 years after it's been specified. :)

Comment: Microsoft has explicitly stated that they're not interested in supporting C past C90 (except for those features that are included in newer C++ standards). See [this interview with Herb Sutter](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/interview-with-herb-sutter/231900562).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your compiler does not support [C99 designated initializers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdesignators.htm).

Perhaps your compiler requires a command line switch to enable C99 features?